# How to resolve java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere, java-7

I am getting the below error when calling SOAP based webservice from SOAP client. This WebService is deployed in  Websphere 8.5.0 with IBM JDK 7.0. however i am able to successfully call and get the response from the same WebService, when i deploy the same ear in WAS with IBM JDK 6.0.Any inputs on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

> java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent;
>   class=com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl,
>   method=createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment;, pc=5 at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94) at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:169) at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.(SOAPPartImpl.java:106)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPPart1_2Impl.(SOAPPart1_2Impl.java:69)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.Message1_2Impl.getSOAPPart(Message1_2Impl.java:89)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.initCharsetProperty(MessageImpl.java:1491)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.init(MessageImpl.java:552)
>   ... 47 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due conflict between the WAS provided Libraries vs WebApp libraries.Finally i am able to fix this issue by making the fallowing changes. Now i am able to deploy the same application on WAS 8.5.0, 8.5.5 with IBM Java 6 or 7.

1. Set the WebModule level class loader property to `Class loaded with local class loader first (parent last)`.
   This can be achieved by using WebSphere admin console

   Applications-> All Applications->Select Application Name->Manage Modules->select a module->class loader order
2. Removed the below dependencies from my project pom

   wsdl4j, axis-saaj, axis-jaxrpc, org.apache.axis, xml-apis,commons-discovery, jaxb-core
3. Added the below dependencies to my project pom

   xalan, xercesImpl, jaxb-apis, jaxb-impl

Answer (score 0):

"Stack shape inconsistent" typically means that a class being used as an argument was changed between when the caller was compiled and when the callee was compiled. The easy fix is to recompile both sides so they are using the same definition of the class.

(Most often, I just recompile my whole project rather than trying to figure out what's out of synch.)

Comment: "Stack shape inconsistent" means the bytecode is invalid, not some class incompatibility.  Recompiling won't fix the problem unless there is a bug in your first compiler that does not exist in the second.